# Python, check whether array elements are all same or not

Tags: python

I have an array, say `[4 4 4 4 4]`, here the length is `5`. In real case it could be `300`. How to check whether all the elements are same, say in this case all are `4`. If all elements have same value, the function return `true`, otherwise `false`. The element could be only interger and value could be either one of them: `0,1,2,3,4`.

I could use a loop in Python as follows. But I am looking for a concise way or simple way to do that, say one line.

```
x= [4,4,4,4]
temp = x[0]

for ele in x:
    if(temp != ele):
        false
     true
```

Comment: `len(set(array)) == 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put elements into `set()` and then check if length of the set is equal to `1`:

```
if len(set(x)) == 1:
    print('All elements are same')
else:
    print('Not same')
```

Answer (score 5):

it might be more efficient not to iterate over the full list (as does the `set` constructor) but to stop at the first element that does not equal `x0`. [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) does that for you:

```
x = [4,4,4,4]
x0 = x[0]

print(all(item == x0 for item in x))
# True
```

this is basically the same version you had; only the loop will be much more efficient this way.

also note that `true` and `false` are not valid python identifiers. in python it is `True` and `False`.